# .show() is not working jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There a text input elements inside each list element. I want to show the input element of the targeted list element.

First I define allEl which selects all the list elements and is now an array. Then i set all of the allEl elements to the class name of ''. Then I select the event's target element. I also define selEl which will be used to find the index number of the list element targeted. Then I loop through all of the list elements and check which one is the targeted element. I set that targeted element's class to 'active' and record the index number of that list element. Then I hid all of the input elements. I then find all of the hidden input elements and assign $hid to it, which will be an array now. Then I use the selEl to show the input element from that list element targeted.

But for some reason, the input element will not show and there is an TypeError saying that $hid[selEl].show is not a function.

```
var allEl = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i = 0; i < allEl.length; i++) {
  allEl[i].className = '';
}
var target = e.target;
var selEl;
$("input:text").hide();
for(var i = 0; i < allEl.length; i++) {
  if(target === allEl[i]) {
    target.className = 'active';
    selEl = i;
  }
}
var $hid = $("input:text:hidden");
$hid[selEl].show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the last line to:

```
$hid.eq(selEl).show();
```

`.eq()` is a `jQuery` method that returns a `jQuery` object.

The `[]` notation returns the plain DOM node. And DOM nodes don't have `show()` method.

Answer (score 1):

$hid[selEl] is the element itself.  $('span').eq(selEl) would give you the jquery-wrapped element at position selEl.

Using this page as example,

```
$('span') ==> n.fn.init[163]
$('span')[1] ==> <span class=​"rep-score">​1,806​</span>​
$('span').eq(1) ==> [span.rep-score]
```

You're trying to use a jQuery method .show() on an element, rather than on the jQuery object that represents that element.